# Keil Dialog Semiconductor

Tags: arm, keil

I'm trying to make a project with keil uVision 5, for DA14580 (Dialog Semiconductor). 
http://www.keil.com/dd/chip/6853.htm
But in Select Device dialog there's no device from Dialog Semiconductor.
**The Question is: How can i start a Project with some selected mcu?**
All examples that i can found is for TI microcontrollers or Atmel.
[image]

Also, Device missing from Pack Installer too:
[image]

The only information about the device that I'm looking at is in device database in File Menu:
[image]

I tried to "Add" the device but, when I'm creating new project for a specific Device, (Photo No1) I cann't find the device in the list.

Comment: Are you trying to create a new project? I have posted a some steps here.    http://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3165/how-to-create-embedded-system-program-from-scratch-using-keil-%C2%B5vision/3167#  If you want post your question on engineering.stackexchange.com I will try to answer. I mostly follow engineering.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Here are some steps for creating a new project for ARM Cortex-M4 using Keil µVision 4.7. This might also help you.

1. Close your current project in keil µVision, menu: projects->close project
2. Select "New uVision Project..." from "Project" menu
   [image]
3. open an empty new one, menu: projects->create a new µVision project
   [image]
4. Select a Target processor
   [image]
5. You get a popup that asks if you want to copy the startup assembler file into your project startup startup_xxxx.s.
   [image]
6. now you see the empty project with just the startup file included.
   [image]
7. Project is ready for embedded software development. It is good idea to rename "Target 1" and "Source Group 1" that describes the project

Right click on Target 1 > Select Manage Project Items -> Update Project Targets, Groups and Files
[image]

8. In order to startup our micro-controller, we need to add 'system_.c' file to our project. Keil already has this file defined. To add manually, Right-click on our "Startup" group and select "Add Existing Files to Group 'Startup'...":

[image]
a.  Keil already have common startup files for some microcontrollers. They are stored at /Keil/ARM/Startup folder
[image]
b.  From there, for my LaunchPad I will move to TI folder, and then TM4C123 folder:
[image]
c.  And there i can see my system_TM4C123.c file:
[image]

9. now you need to add the copied file into the project. project->manage->components,.. or simply click the icon with the three coloured boxes
   add there the startup_TM4C123.c file. you should then see it listed on the left window bar.
10. now create your xxx.c file containing the main procedure.
     you need to add it to the project again, like you did in the previous step.
11. and now you need to set some registers in the controller. for now you can simply do that at the beginning of the main procedure.

**Note 1:** Most the screen shots were created by screen name vasily.sib on piazza forum. I copied these improved them for my purpose.
**Note 2:** I did a cut and paste from [How to create Embedded System Program from Scratch using Keil µVision?](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3165/how-to-create-embedded-system-program-from-scratch-using-keil-%C2%B5vision)

**Reference:**

- [How to create Embedded System Program from Scratch using Keil µVision?](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3165/how-to-create-embedded-system-program-from-scratch-using-keil-%C2%B5vision)
- [Creating a new Project using Keil uVision4](http://users.ece.utexas.edu/~valvano/EE345L/Labs/Fall2011/CreatingProject.pdf)

Comment: I did the step several times. In step 4, it's my problem! See my post, there's nothing about a cpu which i searching for

Comment: First photo of my post it's the problem! I doesn't find the Dialog DA14580 chip,

Comment: Thank you dear Mahendra, your post is useful, but [my problem](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/186531/how-can-i-use-mbed-tls-library-in-my-arm-project-in-keil-ide?noredirect=1#comment384501_186531) is something different I think! I want to use an existing library in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Try Adding a ^(ARM) search string. Below is the screen shot.

[image]

Below is a list of the Search String expression

[image: Search string expressions]

Search String expression Examples

[image: Search String Expression examples]