# How can I use mbed TLS library in my ARM project in Keil IDE?

Tags: arm, embedded, keil

I want to do an RSA encryption/decryption using my AT91SAM7S256  ARM MCU. After googling I found [mbed TLS](https://tls.mbed.org/) library. I download it on my Windows and extracted it in the directory of my project.

I was created the project using Keil IDE as below:

1. *Project >> New mVision Project*
2. Assigning a name to the project
3. Choosing "AT91SAM7S256" under Atmel MCUs
4. Accepting the following suggestion:

[image]

After that, in the following tab, I added the path of *mbed TLS* extracted directory to the *Include Path* of Keil(Path of header files, I think):

*Project >> Option for Target "MyProjectName" >> C\C++*

As the last step I did a right click on the project name in the right sidebar and using *Add files to group AGroupName* I added **rsa.h** and **rsa.c** of mbed TLS files to my project. I added a file named **main.c** that I myself was created it already with the simplest content:

```
#include "rsa.h"

int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

Here are the pictures of above steps:

[image]

[image]

Finally I tried to build this project from *Project >> Build all target files*, but I faced the following error :

```
Build target 'Target 1'
assembling SAM7.s...
compiling rsa.c...
mbedtls-2.0.0\library\rsa.c(30): error:  #5: cannot open source input file "mbedtls/config.h": No such file or directory compiling main.c...
main.c(1): error:  #5: cannot open source input file "rsa.h": No such file or directory Target not created
<</quote>>
```

Well, I added **config.h** to the group just like *rsa.c* and *rsa.h* and replaced **"mbedtls/config.h"** with **"config.h"** in the *rsa.c* file and that error removed. but another similar error appeared. Well I added about 10 files and edit the content as described but I still faced similar error.

1. I want to ask if is this the correct way? Am I should manually add all the files one by one? Or there is a better and efficient way?
2. As the contents of **mbed TLS** library shows(make, makeinstall and so on) and as the extension of downloaded file shows(".tgz"), it is written for linux platform. Does that mean I can't use it in windows?
3. As a starter, witch one is better for the above described project? Keil vs IAR IDE? Windows vs Linux platforms?

*Note that this is the first step of project, I think I must add other algorithms also.*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To get you started, I would look at this question to see how to make a library instead of adding the code manually. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30097062/how-to-include-freetype-library-to-keil-uvision-4

Comment: @Andrew Thank you for the link. Anyway, Am I did something wrong in the above steps?

Comment: I did read the whole question but check this post [Keil Dialog Semiconductor](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/176517/50587)